# Prime-select doesn't work?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 a while ago, and prime-select used to work, but then I did a BIOS update and it hasn't worked since, so I'm stuck on my intel integrated graphics. I purged and re-installed all the nvidia drivers, but when I use `$ sudo prime-select nvidia` and logout, when I log back in, it switches back to the intel integrated graphics. Changing to the gpu from the nvidia x-server settings gui has the same problem. Normally this would be fine, but in order to actually use the nvidia card after prime-selecting it, I have to log out and log back in. I have the nvidia-384* drivers installed, and my motherboard is an Alienware 15 r3.

Comment: Great question, I'm sure others are having similar problems. What motherboard and bios version are you using? Sounds like it works OK when you prime-select or click the gui but will not keep the x.org settings across reboots. It sounds like it is not detecting the right driver for use with the specific nvidia chip you are using. A google for _ubuntu 16.04 x.org nvidia_ came up [with this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) which has some troubleshooting steps.

Comment: @grantbow Thanks, I updated my question to make it more accurate. Please let me know if there's any other information I should provide.